# TeamCity Test Deploy step process exited with code 0 and proceeds to next step even though it encountered an error

Tags: teamcity, continuous-deployment, msdeploy, teamcity-9.0

I have a step in TeamCity where it tests a deploy first before executing the next step(which has a "Execute:if all previous steps finished successfully" option selected). I used .deploy.cmd script and passed /T switch to execute in test mode. The process returns with code 0 but the test deploy returns and error code.

How do I get it to fail and not go to next step? (below is the snapshot of the error)

Thanks,

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOxIY.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Runner type` `PowerShell` for call your cmd script.
When you use PowerShell you can use try-catch structure and return error code > 0 when your code get error.

E.g.:

```
$result = $null
try
{
    $result = &("C:\Users\guest\deploy.cmd") %TestArg%
}
catch
{
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Error "Error on deploy: $errorMessage"
    exit 1
}
echo $result
```

Where, `%TestArg%` is your `Configuration Parameter`, and equals `/T` or nothing.
If your script returns some result, you can parse it and return error code manually

```
if($result.ToLower().Contains("error"))
{
    Write-Error "Deploy operation result contains error(s)"
    exit 1
}
```

**Note:**
As it seemed to me the parameter `Format stderr output as` is responsible only for the color of the display errors in build log.
I use this solution for deploy database via SSDT (SqlPackage.exe), because it not abort building and next steps even in the case of an error

Comment: I went with different solution to add Failure conditions on Build Configuration Settings. I matched the text "Error count: " on "Fail build on specific text in build log" failure condition.